# How to convert a wide dataframe into a vertical dataframe in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have this initial dataframe:

```
  val df_temp = Seq(("Mike",23,"NY","CA","FL"),("Bill",25,"CA","TX","MA"),("Kevin",22,"NY","NJ","CA")).toDF("Name","Age","State1","State2","State3")
```

[image]

I want to transform it into this dataframe:

```
  val df_temp2 = Seq(("Mike",23,"NY"),("Mike",23,"CA"),("Mike",23,"FL"),("Bill",25,"CA"),("Bill",25,"TX"),("Bill",25,"MA"),("Kevin",22,"NY"),("Kevin",22,"NJ"),("Kevin",22,"CA")).toDF("Name","Age","State")
```

[image]

How would I do this?

Thank you so much and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
df_temp.withColumn("States", array($"State1", $"State2", $"State3"))
  .select($"Name", $"Age", explode($"States").as("State"))
```

References for the functions used: [array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#array(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

Comment: If I wanted to pass in a variable set to a large array of columns, how would I do that? I tried map(col):_* but it didnt work